# Calculate the expected time spend playing the game. Hint: Use Wald's Equation.

Tags: random-variables

- Alice and Bob play each other in a checkers tournament, where the first player to win four games wins the match.
- The players are evenly matched, so the probability that each player wins each game is $1$ $2$, independent of all other games.
- The number of minutes for each game is uniformly distributed over the integers in the range $\left[\,{30, 60}\,\right]$, again independent of other games.
- What is the expected time they spend playing the match ?.

I am trying to use Wald's equation in this but very new to this thing. Don't know how to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

For convenience, we can assume that Alice and Bob play on for a total of $\ 7\ $ games, even after one of them has already won.  Then they will play some number, $\ L\ $, of *live* games until one of them has won the match, followed by $\ 7-L\ $ "*dead*" games. Wald's equation tells you that the expected number of games needed to determine who won the match is $\ 45\,\mathbb{E}\left(L\right)$ minutes.

In this problem, the identity $\ \mathbb{E}\left(L\right)=\sum_\limits{n=1}^7\Pr\left(L\le n\right)\ $ is a handy way of calculating $\mathbb{E}\left(L\right)\ $ .
 The probability that Alice has won by the end of game $\ n\ $, for $\ n=4\mbox{–}7\ $, is just the probability of four or more successes in $\ n\ $ Bernoulli trials, or $\ \sum_\limits{j=4}^n \frac{1}{2^n}{n\choose j}\ $. Likewise, the probability of Bob's winning by the end of the $\ n^\mathrm{th}\ $ game is the same.  Thus $\ \Pr\left(L\le n\right)=2\sum_\limits{j=4}^n \frac{1}{2^n}{n\choose j}=\sum_\limits{j=4}^n \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}{n\choose j}\ $.  This should be enough for you to find the answer you're looking for.

**Addendum:** If you don't want to assume that Bob and Alice continue to play each other after the match has been decided, then the probability that Alice wins the match after exactly $\ n\ $ games is the probability  that she wins $\ 3\ $ out of the first $\ n-1\ $, and then wins the $\ n^\mathrm{th}\ $—that is $\ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}{n-1 \choose 3}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\ $.  The probability that Bob wins after exactly $\ n\ $ matches is the same.  Thus, the probability that they take $\ n\ $ or fewer games to decide the match is $\ 2\sum_\limits{j=4}^7\ \frac{1}{2^n}{n-1 \choose 3}=\sum_\limits{j=4}^7\ \frac{1}{2^{n-1}}{n-1 \choose 3}\ $, which is easily checked to give the same value for $\ \Pr\left(L\le n\right)\ $ as before.

Comment: sry I didn't get this idea of 'live' and 'dead' games...

The way I am solving this is that total time both will play the game will be equal to E[T]*E[X] using the wald's equation, where E[T] is the expected number of times the game will be played and E[X] = 45 is the expected time for playing a single game.

Comment: @mskanyal My $\ L\ $ is exactly the same random variable as your $\ T\ $.  The assumption that Alice and Bob continue playing after the match has been decided doesn't affect its distribution.  However, in this case, it's not that much more complicated to work out the distribution without making that assumption, and I've now added an explanation of how to do it.